# Magento 2 Changes Made in Admin Panel do not appear on the Client's Page

Tags: php, magento, magento2

**The problem:**

Changes (e.g. changing products' names) and adding new features (e.g. a new Cart Price Rule) do not work on the Client's Page. All of the changes I do are visible on the Admin Panel right away.

**What I've tried:**

1. Refreshing cache (System => Tools => Cache Management)
   I am selecting 14 out of 15 checkboxes as my senior collegue has said, selecting the "configuration" checkbox may (and probably will) crash the whole site, besides I have been told this "configuration" checkbox has nothing to do with this problem.
2. Flushing Cache
   I have tried both of the options,
   "Flush Cache Storage" & "Flush Magento Cache"
3. Reindexing
   I have typed `bin/magento indexer:reindex` into the OKD console.
   The output of reindexing is alright, as you can see:
   [image: Reindexing]

I could not find any other possible solutions to this problem online, or any other up-to-date post on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have multistore website ?

if yes then make changes in the desired store to get the changes reflected on frontend.